# Did the concept of पंच महाभूत in Indian philosophy evolved from any earlier concept?

Tags: philosophy, darshan

Did the concept of पंच महाभूत in Indian philosophy evolved from any earlier concept?
If, yes, please reference the earlier concept.

Comment: There's nothing like that, except in Indological conception. Indologists perceive that all the siddhāntas of Vaidika darśanas are made-up and influenced or copied from other things which previously existed.
So, they would come up with their own wild theories, like "earlier, there was some concept X, this was later changed into the concept of dharma and then it underwent influences from Y, Z transmuting into W finally. " This is usually nonsense, and doesn't make sense in tradition. The concept of pañcamahābhūta has been there since time immemorial.